# Azure -> Msg 45122 -> Subscriptions are restricted from provisioning in this region. Please choose a different region

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I got a weird error today. When I try to deploy a database to an existing Azure SQL server I get the following error in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

> Could not import package. Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL
>   Server 2016 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues
>   with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient
>   Data Provider: Msg 45122, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 'Subscriptions are
>   restricted from provisioning in this region. Please choose a different
>   region. For exceptions to this rule please contact Microsoft Support.'
>   Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script: CREATE
>   DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
>       (EDITION = 'Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S0', MAXSIZE = 250 GB)  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Why is this? I could create the Sql Server in region `West Europe` without a problem. I'm using the `Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN` subscription in this case.

[image]

Comment: @mjwills West Europe - I could create the server there on this subscription without a problem.

Comment: Does https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9075/when-attempting-to-deploy-i-get-restricted-from-provisioning-in-this-region help? If it doesn't you likely need to contact Support like the exception says.

Comment: @mjwills - Unfortunately not. I'm using `Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription` and `West Europe` is covered. I could also create the server in the first place through their portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant say why this happened. I logged into the Portal and tried to create a database through their website but I got a deploy failed notification almost instantly. This was for an S0 database as well. I then tried to create an S1 database and out of the blue it started working. I then deleted this database and tried to create an S0 again. Now it worked.

This was the first SQL Database I tried to create on this subscription and perhaps some flag was not set yet. Just glad it started working by itself and no support request was needed.